# Bootstrap 4 grid system within Wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'll get quickly to the point: I'm creating a Wordpress theme for my blog, using _s starter theme. I'm using the bootstrap 4 grid system, in order to achieve a 2 column post (on home page/search/archive): the post thumbnail inside a div on the left, while the post content (title, excerpt etc.) on the right.

I want to set the post thumbnail as a background-image of the div, I already achieved that, on desktop/tablet no problem, but on mobile when the thumbnail is above the post content, it won't show up, unless I set a fixed height to the image, I'm ok with that, but the issue is that some posts do not have a post thumbnail, so you can imagine that the result is pretty brutal, with blank space on post without thumbnail;

Maybe this is stupid and easy, but the question is: is there a way to solve this? Maybe it's possible to set the fixed height on mobile but only on posts that has the thumbnail?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="post-thumbnail col-md-5" <?php echo 'style="background-image: url(' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . ')"' ?>>
        </div>

        <div class="post-content <?php echo (has_post_thumbnail())?$small:$large;?>">
        </div> <!-- post content -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- container fluid -->
```

Comment: You'll need to either put a placeholder image there if no image, or use an `<img>` tag and set it's width and height instead of `div.post-thumbnail`

Comment: You also need to add a class of `col-md-7` to the sibling div inside `row` if you want a split article view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, maybe you could try something like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :   the_post(); ?>
            <article>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2>
                      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                      </a>
                    </h2>

                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                        <div class="post-thumbnail" style="background: url('<?php get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>') center center / cover"></div>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <div class="post-thumbnail" style="background: url('[some fixed image url]') center center / cover"></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <p>There no posts to show</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, ultimately I think I achieved what I really want after a couple of tries. I defined a class in the media queries for mobile, set a fixed height of 250px, then, with an inline if statement I assign it only at the post that has the post thumbnail. This is what i wrote

` <?php echo (has_post_thumbnail())?'thumbnail-true':''; ?> `

And it works pretty much well. On mobile, the fixed height is assigned only if the post has the thumbnail, so i don't have blank space in post that doesn't have featured image.